# How do I call a function inside a forEach loop inside a class method Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, class, foreach

I have a function inside a class method that is unread when being called into a forEach loop.

```
class Mazefinder {
  constructor() {
  }

  // class method
  Graph() {

    // This is an arrayList of Objects
    this.vertices = this.mazeArray;
    
    // function I want to use in my forEach loop
    function setKey(key) {
      let setKeyStack = [key];
      return setKeyStack;
    }

    // forEach Loop
    this.vertices.forEach((e) => {
      if (e === s) {
        const keyToAdd = this.nodeIDS + this.nodeIdCount.toString();
        e.setKey()// function setKey cannot be read inside the forEach loop
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I tried attaching it to a this key word

```
this.setKey = setKey
```

but you cannot use the this keyword to attach variables to functions

ex: e.this.setKey(something)// not possible

Comment: I didn't understand the question, you're not calling `setKey`, you need to use parenthesis to call a function

Comment: On my previous post attempt, I realized it was incomplete. The reason why setKey did not have parenthesis was because my VSC intellisense could not read it inside the forEach loop. Therefore, I left it out accidently

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question but I'll try to help :)

I believe you're trying to call a setKey method that is inside a Graph class  from a forEach loop, correct? As I don't have the entire context, I tried to simplify the code and check if that works for you:

```
class Graph {
    constructor() {}

    setKey(key) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}

function main() {
    let vertices = [];
    let graph = new Graph();

    vertices.push(graph);

    vertices.forEach((e) => {
        e.setKey('new key');
    });
}

main();
```

If you run this code the 'new key' will be logged, showing that the setKey method was successfully invoked inside the forEach loop. Was that what you're trying to achieve?

If you need something more specific please post your whole code!
Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think it's not a `class Graph`, but rather the OP has a method `Graph() { … }` *inside* a `class` body. It's really unclear though

Comment: I am so sorry, I realized how unclear I made it and have made adjustments accordingly. Your answer did give me insight of somenew I could try

Comment: Can you provide the whole code or an executable snippet? It's a little bit unclear, but aren't you trying to call a static method on a instantiated object? If you remove the "e." and call only "setKey" you should be able to access, but I'm not a 100% sure if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I found the solution. So, yes, you can call setKey if you remove e object from it due to it being a function in the class method scope. e is an abstraction from another class which has its own methods. What I was trying to do is to add the setKey function to e. However this was not possible since it is in a class of its own. A fix is I create a method in the e class call setKey and add the logic in there.

Comment: Glad you solved. Next time try to post a more complete code snippet, e seemed to be an instance of the MazeFinder, if we knew that it was from another class the solution would be faster! Congrats anyway :)

Comment: I understand, and I will moving forward. Thank you to all those who tried to help in this problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

To call a function `setKey` with `e` as an argument, you have to do it like so:

```js
const setKeyStack = setKey(e);
```